# Strange behavior with python thread pool

Tags: python, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to use python's threadpool

```
concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor
```

I am making an api call and I want to parallelize it using the threadpool executor

Run the api call asynchronously for 1 second

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

initial_start_time = time.time()
count = 0

while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    future = executor.submit(api_call_func)
    end_time = time.time()

    if ((end_time-initial_start_time) > 1):
        break;
    count = count+1
    list.append(future)
print(count)
```

Now when I change the number of workers defined in max_workers from 1 to 10. The count starts decreasing.

```
1 - 10K
5 - 1K
10 - 608
```

So using more workers is actually hurting performance. Why is this happening? I know python uses only one thread at a time. But still since the api call is IO bound, this should have helped.

A single rpc api call takes about 5 ms. It is like bare minimum api with no processing.

Can anyone let me know like what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Um... I cannot understand your structure. You are testing the performance of **adding tasks** but not the performance of running tasks.

The count you get is the number of **added tasks** in one second but not **finished tasks** in one second.

And if you use just one worker, all the other tasks are actually stored in a queue. That doesn't cost anything.

But if you use more workers, for example, 10 workers. When the first ten tasks are submitted, executor will adjust the active threads count which means it will create ten threads one by one. That is costly.

To be clear, when you create an executor, it doesn't create threads at once. Instead, it will create threads only if there are tasks in queue.

Comment: You are right. I am trying to do some benchmarking. How can I get the number of finished tasks in one second to do proper benchmarking? I mean I get the future objects. How can I use them to know the number of finished tasks in a second?

Comment: You can call `future.result()` to wait task to finish. And I think you should first submit some dummy tasks to let executor create all workers before benchmark. That is fair or creating 10 threads will greatly lower the performance.

Comment: What I did was I sent the request asynchronously for 1 second. Then for the next 1 second, I checked which of them were complete and counted them. And the best I could get was like 400 requests completed/second.  That is too low. It is making lots of network IO calls. I am using 10 threads but still why it is so low, the number

Comment: You should use asynchronous structure to send requests. For example, you should use `aiohttp`. With `atiohttp`, you can send thousands of requests concurrently.

Comment: Can I use asyncio? I think it is similar to aiohttp. I am not sure how to use that.

Comment: `aiohttp` is based on `asyncio` and provides a requests-like API. You know, for human. Basic `asyncio` is for... um... Ultron.

Comment: I can't use aiohttp because it's more like a grpc call. So I have to use asyncio

Comment: I used aiohttp. But still it's not scaling that much. Would really appreciate some suggestion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970639/async-calls-using-aiohttp-not-scaling