# Async calls using aiohttp not scaling

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to use aiohttp to make http calls. The max throughput I can get is 1K requests/sec. The server is not doing any processing, but just acking the requests right away. It takes around 7ms for the RTT of the request.

The profiling of the python process shows something like this. I tried to make 2K request asynchronously and it took more than 2 seconds for them to finish.

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     3720    0.905    0.000    0.905    0.000 {method 'poll' of 'select.epoll' objects}
     2000    0.142    0.000    0.158    0.000 {method 'feed_data' of 'aiohttp._http_parser.HttpParser' objects}
    11500    0.081    0.000    1.958    0.000 grpc.py:113(request)
     9500    0.080    0.000    1.760    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:180(_request)
     3720    0.069    0.000    3.634    0.001 /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py:1330(_run_once)
     4000    0.064    0.000    0.064    0.000 {method 'send' of '_socket.socket' objects}
     4000    0.063    0.000    0.067    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:635(_prepare_headers)
     6000    0.053    0.000    0.215    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/idna/core.py:231(check_label)
    54000    0.053    0.000    0.104    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/idna/intranges.py:38(intranges_contain)
    26509    0.050    0.000    2.608    0.000 /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:125(_run)
     5500    0.045    0.000    0.364    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py:723(_create_connection)
182134/182126    0.045    0.000    0.067    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
     1500    0.042    0.000    0.042    0.000 {method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects}
     2000    0.040    0.000    0.178    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py:477(send)
      382    0.040    0.000    0.040    0.000 {built-in method marshal.loads}
     9500    0.034    0.000    2.083    0.000 grpc.py:65(grpc)
```

How can I improve the throughput?

Here is my implementation

```
def _get_session_headers() -> dict:
    """Get session headers."""
    return {
        // Some key value for headers
    }

conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1000)
_session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn,headers=_get_session_headers())

def _get_uri(path: str) -> str:
    """Get URI."""
    return urljoin("http://targethost:8080/", path)    

async def make_request(
               path: str,
               grequest: Message,
               index, int
               headers: dict = {},
               **kwargs: dict) -> None:

    async with request('POST', _get_uri(path), data=grequest, headers=headers, **kwargs) as response:
    print("Before " + str(index))
    buffer = await response.read()
    print("After " + str(index))

@async_contextmanager
async def request(method: str, path: str, **kwargs: dict) -> aiohttp.ClientResponse:
    async with _session.request(method, _get_uri(path), **kwargs) as res:
        yield res




async def test(req, index):
    await make_request('fetch', req, index)




grequest = initialize_data() // Some sample data to be sent 

start = time.time()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = []

start = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(test(grequest, i)))


print("Starting the loop")
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
end = time.time()

task=loop.create_task(_session.close())
loop.run_until_complete(task)
loop.close()
print(end-start)
```

This is printing like 1 second. So my rps is just 1k/sec.

```
Before buffer 896
After buffer 896
Before buffer 976
After buffer 976
Before buffer 880
After buffer 880
Before buffer 898
After buffer 898
Before buffer 882
After buffer 882
Before buffer 978
After buffer 978
Before buffer 900
After buffer 900
Before buffer 884
After buffer 884
Before buffer 982
After buffer 982
Before buffer 902
After buffer 902
Before buffer 886
After buffer 886
Before buffer 904
After buffer 904
Before buffer 988
After buffer 988
Before buffer 888
After buffer 888
Before buffer 990
After buffer 990
Before buffer 994
After buffer 994
```

It looked like they were executing serially. However, if I replace 
`buffer = await response.read()` with `buffer = await asyncio.sleep(1)`, the prints are intermingled.

I also validated that it is the case with this tutorial script

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url, session, index):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        print("Before " + str(index))
        buffer = await response.read()
        print("After " + str(index))

async def run(r):
    url = "http://google.com"
    tasks = []

    # Fetch all responses within one Client session,
    # keep connection alive for all requests.
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url, session, i))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        # you now have all response bodies in this variable
        print(responses)

def print_responses(result):
    print(result)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(4))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

For 10000 requests, this is what I got from the profiler

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    35901   10.792    0.000   10.792    0.000 {method 'poll' of 'select.epoll' objects}
    20000    0.607    0.000    0.607    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:635(_prepare_headers)
    35901    0.397    0.000   22.202    0.001 /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py:1330(_run_once)
    33500    0.393    0.000    7.911    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:180(_request)
    63007    0.345    0.000    0.430    0.000 /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py:594(_call_soon)
    20000    0.341    0.000    0.341    0.000 {method 'send' of '_socket.socket' objects}
    10000    0.311    0.000    0.311    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'multidict._multidict.CIMultiDict' objects}
   270000    0.282    0.000    0.557    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/idna/intranges.py:38(intranges_contain)
    30000    0.263    0.000    1.103    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/idna/core.py:231(check_label)
    10000    0.246    0.000    0.355    0.000 {method 'feed_data' of 'aiohttp._http_parser.HttpParser' objects}
```

Comment: Refactor your coroutines so they work correctly?  From the profile where do you think the bottleneck is?  Without your implementation how would anyone know where a problem might be?

Comment: @wwii. Updated the post with my implementation. Could you please provide some suggestion?

Comment: Change `for i in range(1000)` to `for i in range(10000)` and check the performance.

Comment: @Sraw. For 2000 it was 2.5 seconds, for 3000 it was 5 seconds and for 10000 it was 19 seconds

Comment: @Sraw For 2000 it was 2.5 seconds, for 3000 it was 5 seconds and for 10000 it was 19 seconds

Comment: `aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1000)` - is this limit throttling execution? Does it force some serial execution into the scheme when you ask for (significantly) more than the limit?

Comment: Have you tried instrumenting your coroutines to get a feel for how things are being processed.  Maybe lower the connection limit to a reasonable *testing* value and then make tasks below and above the limit.  Just some simple prints before and after the `await`s like [these examples](https://hackernoon.com/asyncio-for-the-working-python-developer-5c468e6e2e8e) .

Comment: @wwii. I added the print statements as you mentioned. At first it looked like they are executing serially.

Comment: However, if I replace the buffer = await response.read() statement with buffer  = asyncio.sleep(1), they seem to be intermingled which means it's not serial. Probably the request response fetch is fast enough

Comment: @wwii. Updated my post. Please provide any suggestion you have